# Issue on Adding Animation Effect to Active Class

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Can you please take a look at [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/xc62b2zg/) and let me know why I am not able to add the animate effect to active class through jquery

I have class called

```
.sliding-middle-out {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.sliding-middle-out:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

now I would like to add the same animation effect to the active class without having the hover effect involeved. What i did is merging the hover part inthe after like

```
.sliding-middle-out:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

and adding the class `.sliding-middle-out` into the `.active` class like

```
 $("button").click(function(){
        $(".active").addClass("sliding-middle-out");
 });
```

which is adding the class without animation effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need style the `:after` on the `.active` class to makes the effect working. Check this:

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahdaen/xc62b2zg/1/)

Comment: Thanks Nanang Mahedaen El-agun! Long Name !  :-)

Comment: Hi again Nanangdo you have any idea how to do this job on click over the tabs as well?